# Looping through array and checking if the artist matches the artist that the user entered then displaying the details of the song

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a foreach loop so that it goes through each item of the array. I have tried to put stuff in my if statement but nothing i try seems to compile iv'e tries putting in songs'getartist but that won't work as it's a method.

I needto check if the artist matches the artist that the user entered, or if the user presses return without entering an artist then it should display the details of the song.

I assume that the second part uses the keyread function but i'm not fully sure how to use it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Song[] songs = new Song[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.Length; i++)
        {
            songs[i] = InputSongDetails();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");

        foreach (var song in songs)
        {
            if ()
            {

            }
        }

    }


    static Song InputSongDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
        string artist = Console.ReadLine();

        int records;
        Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
        }
        return new Song(name, artist, records);
    }
}
```

Song class

```
class Song
{
    string name;
    string artist;
    int copiesSold;

    public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
    }

    public Song()
    {
    }

    public string GetArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public string GetDetails()
    {
        return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
    }

    public string GetCertification()
    {
        if (copiesSold < 200000)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (copiesSold < 400000)
        {
            return "Silver";
        }
        if (copiesSold < 600000)
        {
            return "Gold";
        }
        return "Platinum";
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in order to clarify: in your `foreach` body you should
- ask the user for an artist name
- if the user enters an artist name, show whether the *current* son's artist matches
- if the user leaves input blank, show full details for *current* song
Have I understand correctly?

Comment: Your code is already reading input and you're asking how to read input? It looks like you could benefit from a basic programming course rather than someone just giving you the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing couple of things.

First You need to read the artist name from user.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");
var artist = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then You need to filter the songs list based on user entry,

```
foreach (var song in songs)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(artist) || song.GetArtist().Equals(artist))
   {
    Console.WriteLine(song.GetDetails());
   }
}
```

Btw, to show another way of doing this, you could also make use of Linq here.

```
var filteredList= songs.Where(song=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(artist) || song.GetArtist().Equals(artist))
                       .Select(song=> song.GetDetails());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filteredList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ReadKey, I think you should use ReadLine, which allows the user to enter a string followed by Enter.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");
var name = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (var song in songs)
{
    if (song.GetArtist() == name || name == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(song.GetDetails());
    }
}
```

Comment: Iv'e tried this the problem with this is it won't compile as song.artist in inaccesible